# JSF passthrough dropdown/h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, passthrough-elements

I'm having some issues with HTML dropdown. I searched in the web and found this stackoverflow link realated to my issue 
[HTML 5 dropdown and JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867735/html-5-dropdown-and-jsf-2-2)

I could't use jsfc atribute as suggested in the link. My  attribute don't recognize this attr. Do I have to import this attr from an URL?

My error occurs exactly in this line

```
<ui:repeat value="#{appBean.frentes}" var="frente" jsfc="f:selectItems">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version?

Comment: Sorry for my dumbness, Balus. How to do it?

Comment: Which JSF implementation are you using? (to make it easy, there are currently only two widely used ones: Mojarra and MyFaces) And then which version of it exactly (e.g. "Mojarra 2.1.29" or "MyFaces 2.1.17", etc)? You can find it in webapp startup log.

Comment: Mojarra 2.2.7
Glassfish 4.1 ( build 13 )

Comment: Works for me when starting with a completely blank JSF project with everything set to default. I only didn't use GlassFish, but WildFly.